# Payment of SEVIS in the USA

Tags: visas, usa, fees-and-charges

Can my family in the USA pay for my SEVIS fee if I am from Nigeria? I have an I-20 already, but making the payment is what has been a challenge for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can, according to the Department of Homeland Security.

> [How do I pay the I-901 SEVIS Fee?](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/paying-the-i-901-sevis-fee)
>   A prospective F or M student with a country of citizenship or country of birth of Cameroon, Ghana, Kenya, Nigeria or Gambia must pay by money order, Western Union Quick Pay or certified check drawn from a U.S. bank. All other prospective F or M students also have the option to make a credit card payment on [FMJfee.com](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fmjfee.com%2Fi901fee%2F).
>
> SEVP will accept third party payments, meaning someone else can pay your I-901 SEVIS Fee using the same method of payment. For students who cannot pay the fee by credit card, third party payers are also restricted from paying the fee by credit card.